# blower on Goodman Furnance/A/C is working but only slowly, barley pushes out heat or A/C

Tags: blower

Furnace and A/C work, blower fan is spinning but there is no force coming out of the vents, almost a whisper if any

Comment: Your fan may need some lubrication when the lube in the bearings is no longer doing its job the motor will not spin fast enough to provide enough air flow, that or your filter is really filthy.

Comment: Common cause of this is a blown cap in the blower motor power input.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this unit. Any chance the fan belt is slipping?

Comment: Is this old equipment that used to work better? Or new equipment that isn’t working as expected?